# Room database retrieve data from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I use google maps in my project and i try to retrieve Latitude and Longitude and add marker to the map from SQLite database. When I try to retrieve I receive **Null**. Where is problem?

Below u can find my code

```
class App : Application() {
    var database: markerDatabase? = null
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this

        database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, markerDatabase::class.java, "stopmarker.db")
            .createFromAsset("databases/stopmarker.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
    }

    companion object {
        var instance: App? = null
    }
}
```

```
interface markerDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM bus_stop")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Marker>>

   @Query("SELECT title FROM bus_stop")
   fun getTitle(): LiveData<List<String>>

    @Query("SELECT lat FROM bus_stop")
   fun getLatitude(): LiveData<List<Double>>

    @Query("SELECT lon FROM bus_stop")
    fun getLongitude(): LiveData<List<Double>>
}
```

```
abstract class markerDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun MarkerDao(): markerDAO?
}
```

In MainActivity

```
val db = App.instance

val lat = db?.database?.MarkerDao()?.getLatitude()

val lon = db?.database?.MarkerDao()?.getLongitude()

       Log.i("My_Tag",lat?.value?.get(1).toString())
```

Result: **Null**

Comment: You should use a debugger and see which part of that long chain of `?.` operators is null.

Answer (score 0):

LiveData load data lazily and if you want observe any changes in it then you should use an **Oserver** and update UI accordingly. For this you will need to follow MVVM design pattern. It's quite simple.

But if you only want to recieve data then use **Coroutines**.

```
@Query("SELECT lat FROM bus_stop")
suspend fun getLatitude(): List<Double>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to implement into my code?